# Проверка на нахождение в enum. Java

Tags: java, enum

Как проверить нахождение константы в enum'e, которая соответствует введенной строке с консоли?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для enum-а:

```
enum Foo {
    VALUE1, VALUE2     
}
```

Проверить есть ли в нем значение переменной `inputString`

```
String inputString = ...
boolean exists = true; 
try {
     Foo.valueOf(inputString);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     exists = false;
}
```

для строки `inputString = "VALUE1"` переменная `exist` будет `true`

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать библиотеку guava

Зависимость:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Код:

```
com.google.common.base.Enums.getIfPresent(EnumClass.class, value).orNull()
```